# Static dissipative ESD footware

Tags: safety, esd

Are shoes like this used in professional labs or is this just a gimmick?

http://www.esdshoe.com/products/Lightweight-Classic-Mid-High-ESD-Composite--Basketball-Shoe-%252d-Men%27s.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never seen such things advertised before BUT I have every reason to think they are serious. The site in questi0n sells shows signs of having been there for at least 2 years and they sell only anti ESD footware. A good first indication of credibility.

In many cases search engine results for a selected product start to turn up garbage and unrelated results in many cases after the first few pages. If you do a
 [Gargoyle search for "heel grounders" and then look at the results around the 500th results](http://www.google.co.nz/#q=%22heel+grounder%22&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&ei=b4fYTqvuIoihiQLPucXjCQ&start=500&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=31314425282797f7&biw=2304&bih=1245)

ALL the entries are still specifically about the expected anti-ESD product.
 500 entries for "heel grounders is impressive - assuming they are not padding their results - as may be the case. Chinese sellers of a product tend to advertise many pages and hundreds of instances of a product even when they sell say 5 or 10 actual products. I haven't checked but this may greatly skew the results.

- **Real world**

I have visited a range of factories in China - with the bottom end ones having no concept whatsoever re requirements for taking ESD precautions.  But in the  "realest" factories that I visited, where products were manufactured for name brand international electronics giants, all visitors had to don "lab coats" and protective hair covers. Visitors either had to (various locations) add heel grounders to their shoes, or leave their shoes in a rack and wear supplied clean and ESD safe footwear, or to place tasteful shoe enveloping conductive and dirt protective overshoes over their shoes (no part of own shoes touches floor). Some management staff wore apparently conventional shoes but with heel grounders. ALL work trays for carrying components or semi finished products were of ESD safe materials and a significant number of negative ion blowers were in use throughout. Signs summarising ESD safe and other work practices were prominently displayed. ie there is no doubt that they were highly serious about the issue - enough so that it would impact their effective overall productivity if unnecessary in locations where throughput cost high tech $. I've also seen factories where eg COB level manufacturing (blob on board) and LCD assembly where "sensible" protective measures were taken (wrist straps, work surfaces) but with no apparent use of heel grounders or ion blowers.

**How real is ESD danger?**

When I first saw this question I thought it said something about general opinions in this forum being that ESD protection matters but can be treaed relatively casually. I don't see that remark there now  - it may have been deleted or I may have seen it elsewhere.

While I myself have commented about ESD protection being oversold by the sellers of protective equipment, it is a very real phenonenom and there is no doubt that damage can happen. I have mentioned here personal experiences of ESD damage happening under under specified conditions and vanishing when problem sources were addressed. Shoes are not the only way to deal with such problems but in an environment were the floor surface was properly controlled they may be cheaper and as effective as wrist straps and similar.

Comment: In places that I have worked we have had conductive flooring, both hard floor and conductive carpets, and wore heel grounding straps on our shoes.  I would agree that for production environments a special ESD shoe makes perfect sense.

Comment: How real is ESD danger.  it is hard to quantify because it typically does not cause immediate fatalities, it tends to cause early failures in your product.  If these failures happen shortly after delivery to the end customer then the damage to your reputation and bottom line can be severe - in my case most of the units that I make are physically inaccessible (floating on an ocean current) so a failure is catastrophic.

Comment: Gargoyle will likely return lots of unrelated results, check the appropriate section of [your](http://www.stanleysupplyservices.com/search.aspx?f=1%3a1012) [favorite](http://www.newark.com/heel-toe-grounders) [distributor](http://www.alliedelec.com/grounding/shoe-straps/) for more targeted information.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer - Did you read what I said? (seious question).  My point was that for heel grounders the results from say 500-509 were all relevant. I tried a few other places in the 1st 500 and all I checked were relevant.I don't know that I've seen such a good match before".

Comment: @Russel - Yeah, I read it, but what's the use of links to patents, questionable online stores, and links to random products?  The distributor links categorize this stuff, provide datasheets in consistent locations, don't change much, are reputable sellers, and are where the OP really wants to go, IMO.  I'd rather link to a distributor than to Google.

Answer (score 5):

Not often. However, ESD-protective footwear is no gimmick and is practiced in most every professional lab.

### ***Are these used often?***

No, the ordinary method is a heel strap, like [this one from 3M](http://www.stanleysupplyservices.com/product-detail.aspx?pn=424-800):

[image]

The black part is conductive rubber.

The yellow part (it's that color so you can easily verify that everyone's wearing one) is elastic + velcro.  The grey part (extending up towards the sock) is a conductive fabric that gets tucked into the shoe.

These are much cheaper than a conductive shoe, and employees can wear whatever shoe they find most comfortable.

The linked shoe is for individuals who don't want to wear a heel strap.  Perhaps it's a fashion thing?  Maybe if you wear one every day, it gets uncomfortable?  Perhaps it's a performance thing, and the target individuals are playing dodge-ball while carrying circuit boards?

### ***Are these a gimmick?***

Assuming that they perform a similar function to the heel straps, no, they're not a gimmick.

ESD is real.  Walking around, with your pantlegs rubbing and your shoes scuffing the floor, is an easy way to build up static energy:

[image]

If Thor, the Dog of Thunder, touched a PCB in this state, it would likely be damaged, though probably not as badly as Dilbert in [the next panel](http://dilbert.com/fast/1990-01-10/).

If you're already grounded via a wrist strap, these are superfluous.  However, if you unplug and walk away to do any of these common tasks:

- Refill a pick-n-place
- Move PCBs from one assembly area to another
- Walk away from a workstation and return without dissipating static

then you really need static protection linking your feet to the floor.   Of course, if you're standing on something like polyester carpet, this won't do any good, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you that the techs who work on the clean-rooms/manufacturing floor where I work absolutely where special lab coats, footwear, and grounded wrist straps to prevent electro-static discharge from damaging components, solder joints, etc. It's not a gimmick or a joke when it comes to reliability in manufacturing. Once cards get coated the risk of ESD goes down somewhat, but even then we are required to transport them around in ESD protected boxes and handle them with grounded wrist straps and ESD lab coats.

But that's just in my professional life. I am, admittedly, quite lax with respect to ESD in my hobby/microcontroller life, but I think I get away with it because I use through hole parts and hand solder everything. I certainly don't wear any kind of special garb when working with electronics at home. But an ESD mat and a wrist strap is a good idea for peace of mind.